# Crystal Reports limit Select Expert dropdown

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How do I limit the Select Expert drop downdown to only a few records which I want in there?
In the image, the dropdown which I am referring to is the one with "01-NON-Exempt" in it.  This dropdown pulls all records from the hrtables.fdesc field.  I want to limit the records to only a select few which will populate this dropdown.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog you're trying to use (Select Expert) is a *design-time* feature, and it will show all the records in the dropdown. The only way to change/restrict what it shows is to change/restrict what the database returns.

What you are probably looking for is a way to offer a similar dropdown to users at report *run-time*. **That's what parameters are for.**  You can provide a parameter with a list of values (which can be a subset of field values), and when a user refreshes the report, they will be prompted to choose a value from the list.

For some more details, I did a quick search and found [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=683066&seqNum=3) article (pages 3-4) seems to be a decent explanation of how to create a parameter and use it in the record select expert.